# can't understand nodejs response in react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

from an axios POST in my react app,  I do a post in node, and I have been returning an array similar to...

```
[
 {
  thing1: 'something1',
  thing2: 'something2',
  thing3: 'something3'
},
{
  thing1: 'somethingdifferent1',
  thing2: 'somethingdifferent2',
  thing3: 'somethingdifferent3',
}
]
```

Then on the react side I have

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/searchData', { search_obj })
        .then(resp => {
setData(resp['data'])
}
```

This all works well. For a guy 2 weeks into his JavaScript journey.

If I pack more data into the response, so I now send out from nodejs ...

```
    [
     [
     {
      thing1: 'something1',
      thing2: 'something2',
      thing3: 'something3'
     },
     {
      thing1: 'somethingdifferent1',
      thing2: 'somethingdifferent2',
      thing3: 'somethingdifferent3',
     }
     ],
     [
      { new_stuff: 'value'}
     ]
   ]
```

I can see in react that resp['data'] has 2 arrays, with the data I sent. But for the life of me I can't do anything to use it effectively ... once I go `setData(resp['data'])` then try and `console.log(data)` it is empty every time...

to compound my confusion further, there is code later on in the react app, that does a data.length and actually gets the answer 2. Which is correct, except I can't see anything in data with a console.log

Apologies if this is not enough info, let me know whet else you need to help a guy out.

Answer (score 0):

try clonning the data object instead of passing it as reference (notice the spread operator)...

```js
setData( [ ...resp['data'] ] )
```

Comment: data only contains the first array in resp['data'] when I do that, but at least it has something I can see now.... could this be due to my `data` schema having to change to reflect what I am trying to put into it now ?

Comment: when you set an object using a setter callback like setData, react will do "stuff" on that object, so anytime you pass it something make sure it is a clean object with no other code referencing it... when you directly passed the data like in your first post you risk another code mabe resetting the data or doing some type of cleanup on it... mabe that is what was happening. Also i thought you wanted that array containing arrays, you can do [...resp.data[0]] if you just want the child array.

Comment: Yes, I did want the array or arrays, but it is like I am doing ...resp.data[0]] ... so it's probably something else interfering